# Proguard obfuscated jar won't launch

Tags: java, jar, javafx, obfuscation, proguard

I was having trouble running my obfuscated jar, I got the "Java Virtual Machine Launcher" message "A Java Exception has occurred" when I try to run it. (This error is a popup, not on the command line) I tried running from the command line and printing the stacktrace from the jvm console and didn't see any exceptions.

So I did a little troubleshooting: I disabled shrinking, obfuscating AND optimizing so that the output (should be) the same as the input. The output jar turned out to be a few KB less than the input. I extracted both jars, decompiled the .class files and compared the source of every single file and the MANIFEST.MF and they were all the same*!

I'm using ProGuard 4.10, JDK 1.7.0_25 x64 and Windows 8. I'm building a fairly elaborate JavaFX program and I believe I properly configured ProGuard- but that shouldn't matter anymore if shrinking, obfuscating and optimizing are all disabled, right? Here are the notes that ProGuard gives me:

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [netscape.javascript.JSException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [netscape.javascript.JSObject]
Note: com.javafx.main.Main accesses a field 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' dynamically
Note: com.javafx.main.Main accesses a field 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' dynamically
Note: com.javafx.main.Main accesses a declared method 'reset()' dynamically
Note: com.javafx.main.Main$2 accesses a field 'ERROR_MESSAGE' dynamically
```

When I first tried obfuscating, I skipped com.javafx.main.** but I still got those messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I had no problems running my jar before it processed by ProGuard. Thanks.

***EDIT**: When doing a binary comparison, the manifest files differ (the original is longer) but doing an ASCII comparison both files are identical.  All other files are completely identical.  The difference between the two MANIFEST.MF files is PC vs. UNIX line breaks.

***EDIT2**: I ran the file with the -jar option, and I did get an explicit exception!

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

From com.javafx.main.Main here is the use of ERROR_MESSAGE and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:

```
int ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE_Field.getInt(null);

Method showMessageDialogMethod = jOptionPaneClass.getMethod("showMessageDialog", new Class[] { componentClass, Object.class, String.class, Integer.TYPE });

showMessageDialogMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { null, this.val$string, "JavaFX Launcher Error", new Integer(ERROR_MESSAGE) });
```

...

```
Field HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_Field = winRegistryClass.getField("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE");
int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_Field.getInt(null);
String path = (String)mGet.invoke(null, new Object[] { new Integer(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), "Software\\Oracle\\JavaFX\\" + version, "Path" });
```

Comment: What have you done to search out use of Class methods forName, getMethod, getField, etc. methods, as outlined in the ProGuard manual?

Comment: @rcook I verified that those Class methods were not processed by not processing *any* methods of *any* Class.  In fact I disabled all obfuscation, decompiled the resultant jar and verified that all source files were unchanged.  I might not understand your comment or you might not understand my question.  Has anyone experienced a problem like this before?  Thanks.

Comment: I meant by the program, not by ProGuard.  Does the program use reset() or ERROR_MESSAGE in any of the forName() or reflection forms?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. None of my classes use reset() or ERROR_MESSAGE.  Compiling my javafx program in Netbeans it adds com.javafx.main.Main and com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback. Neither of those classes uses a reset() method, and only javafx.main.Main uses ERROR_MESSAGE (I'll post the code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar was signed; I made an unsigned version and it obfuscated correctly!

Comment: how to make it unsigned ?